# I am trying to pass the size of a <DIV> back to google app engine (Python code) but can't seem to make it work

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

Many apologies if I'm being really dopey here - I've been searching most of the morning for the answer to this but maybe I'm searching in the wrong terms.  I'm using Google App Engine, with Python code to set up my webapp. I've managed to set up the basic page structure using the following HTML code:

```
main_html = """
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/main.css">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <DIV class="wspace">
      <BR>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="header">
      <FONT class="logoFont">Logo Text</font>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="maincontainer">
      <DIV class="sidebar" id="leftsidebar">
        <SCRIPT>
          var lsCanWid = document.getElementsByTagName("div"["leftsidebar"].offsetWidth
          var lsCanHei = document.getElementsByTagName("div")["leftsidebar"].offsetHeight
        </SCRIPT> 
      </DIV>
      <DIV class="sidebar" id="rightsidebar">
        <SCRIPT>
          var rsCanWid = document.getElementsByTagName("div")["rightsidebar"].offsetWidth
          var rsCanHei = document.getElementsByTagName("div")["rightsidebar"].offsetHeight
        </SCRIPT>
      </DIV>
      <DIV class="mainscreen" id="mainscr">
        <SCRIPT>
          var mainCanWid = document.getElementsByTagName("div")["mainscr"].offsetWidth
          var mainCanHei = document.getElementsByTagName("div")["mainscr"].offsetHeight
        </SCRIPT>
        %(MAINCONTENT)s
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="footer">
      Footer Text
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="wspace">
      <FONT class="crnotice">Copyright Notice Text</FONT>
    </DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
"""
```

I've tested the javascript variables, and these work exactly as planned (lsCanWid returns the left sidebar width for example).

I've then got the following code in my Python:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        lsCanWid = self.request.get('lsCanWid')
        lsCanHei = self.request.get('lsCanHei')
        rsCanWid = self.request.get('rsCanWid')
        rsCanHei = self.request.get('rsCanHei')
        mainCanWid = self.request.get('mainCanWid')
        mainCanHei = self.request.get('mainCanHei')
        temp_str = str(lsCanWid)
        self.response.write(main_html %{"MAINCONTENT": temp_str})

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

I've not tried to use self.request.get within a "get" before, so I'm not sure if this is the problem.  The python code is working fine if you replace temp_str with some other string, so that's not where my issue lies.  I'd be really grateful of any help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - You aren't sending these values back to your handler, you need to add them to the query string or post them back.

Javascript runs the browser. Once the page has rendered in the browser, there is no connection with your back end code. In order for your Python code to know anything from the browser, you have to send it back to the code. This is just how HTTP works. Its a "request/response" cycle and there is no connection once the response (what you send to the browser) is finished.

So, to send these values back to your code you need to append them to the request as part of a query string, something like `/foo?lsCanWid=3&lsCanHei=4` (and so on). You would need to build this URL using javascript, and then add it to a link which you would have to click - then, on the *next request* (once this new link is clicked), your Python code will receive the values.

Comment: Thanks so much for your speedy response. That makes a lot of sense. Very much appreciated!